# How to get fields and submit button in the same html div in django forms.Form

Tags: python, django-forms

I am working on a tutorial:

Here is my views.py:

```
class NewTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task = forms.CharField(label="New Task")
    priority = forms.IntegerField(label="Priority", min_value=1, max_value=5)

def addtask(request):
    return render(request, "task/add.html", {
        "form": NewTaskForm(),
        })
```

my html-code:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>Add task</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'task:add' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'task:index' %}">Go back</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Why does every element appear in its own div?

I expected all fields and add-button in one row:
[see screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbbta.png)

but get one element per line:
[screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZPMM.png)